# JSONDecoder not decoding API data

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to get a JSON object via API that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "book_id": "MAT",
            "book_name": "Matthew",
            "book_name_alt": "Matthew",
            "chapter": 1,
            "chapter_alt": "1",
            "verse_start": 1,
            "verse_start_alt": "1",
            "verse_end": 1,
            "verse_end_alt": "1",
            "verse_text": "The book of the genealogy of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham."
        },
        {
            "book_id": "MAT",
            "book_name": "Matthew",
            "book_name_alt": "Matthew",
            "chapter": 1,
            "chapter_alt": "1",
            "verse_start": 2,
            "verse_start_alt": "2",
            "verse_end": 2,
            "verse_end_alt": "2",
            "verse_text": "Abraham was the father of Isaac, and Isaac the father of Jacob, and Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,"
        }
    ]
}
```

My function gets the data successfully, however it doesn't get progress past the JSONDecoder() line. Perhaps I haven't written the structs or .decode() correctly? Or do I have to use `CodingKeys` or `unkeyedContainer` ?I have deleted the url and key below for obvious reasons.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var verses: [Verse]
}

struct Verse: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var book_id: String
    var book_name: String
    var book_name_alt: String
    var chapter: Int
    var chapter_alt: String
    var verse_start: Int
    var verse_start_alt: String
    var verse_end: Int
    var verse_end_alt: String
    var verse_text: String
}

func getText() async {
        let urlString = "..."
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("...", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
        request.setValue("...", forHTTPHeaderField: "v")
        
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                verses = decodedResponse.verses
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data")
        }
    }
```

The function should get the data, decode it into a swift struct so that I can then display the verse text in a scrollview. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can see that the json data you show does not have a `verses`, it has `data`. So at least change this to 
decode it into your models. Use `struct Response: Codable {
    var data: [Verse]
}`

Comment: Don't throw away the decoding error. print it

Comment: Also in `Verse`, use `let id = UUID()`, not `var`. Or use the appropriate `CodingKeys` without the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decoding json data, you need the models to **match** the json data.
You can use `CodingKeys` to change the names of the properties, such as:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var verses: [Verse]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case verses = "data"
    }
        
}

struct Verse: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let chapter, verseStart, verseEnd: Int
    let bookID, bookName, bookNameAlt, chapterAlt: String
    let verseStartAlt, verseEndAlt, verseText: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case chapter
        case bookID = "book_id"
        case bookName = "book_name"
        case bookNameAlt = "book_name_alt"
        case chapterAlt = "chapter_alt"
        case verseStart = "verse_start"
        case verseStartAlt = "verse_start_alt"
        case verseEnd = "verse_end"
        case verseEndAlt = "verse_end_alt"
        case verseText = "verse_text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use `.convertFromSnakeCase` on the `JSONDecoder` so you don't need all of those `CodingKeys` in `Verse`.